# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'errno'

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I placed a `ClientConnectionError` exception in a `multiprocessing.Queue` that was generated by `asyncio`. I did this to pass an exception generated in asyncio land back to a client in another thread/process.

My assumption is that this exception occurred during the deserialization process reading the exception out of the queue. It looks pretty much impossible to reach otherwise.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_neural_simplified.py", line 318, in <module>
    main(**arg_parser())
  File "model_neural_simplified.py", line 314, in main
    globals()[command](**kwargs)
  File "model_neural_simplified.py", line 304, in predict
    next_neural_data, next_sample = reader.get_next_result()
  File "/project_neural_mouse/src/asyncs3/s3reader.py", line 174, in get_next_result
    result = future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "model_neural_simplified.py", line 245, in read_sample
    f_bytes = s3f.read(read_size)
  File "/project_neural_mouse/src/asyncs3/s3reader.py", line 374, in read
    size, b = self._issue_request(S3Reader.READ, (self.url, size, self.position))
  File "/project_neural_mouse/src/asyncs3/s3reader.py", line 389, in _issue_request
    response = self.communication_channels[uuid].get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 113, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aiohttp/client_exceptions.py", line 133, in __init__
    super().__init__(os_error.errno, os_error.strerror)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'errno'
```

I figure it's a long shot to ask, but does anyone know anything about this issue?

> Python 3.6.8, aiohttp.__version__ == 3.6.0

Update:

I managed to reproduce the issue (credit to Samuel in comments for improving the minimal reproducible test case, and later xtreak at bugs.python.org for furthing distilling it to a pickle-only test case):

```
import pickle

ose = OSError(1, 'unittest')

class SubOSError(OSError):

    def __init__(self, foo, os_error):
        super().__init__(os_error.errno, os_error.strerror)

cce = SubOSError(1, ose)
cce_pickled = pickle.dumps(cce)
pickle.loads(cce_pickled)


./python.exe ../backups/bpo38254.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/karthikeyansingaravelan/stuff/python/cpython/../backups/bpo38254.py", line 12, in <module>
    pickle.loads(cce_pickled)
  File "/Users/karthikeyansingaravelan/stuff/python/cpython/../backups/bpo38254.py", line 8, in __init__
    super().__init__(os_error.errno, os_error.strerror)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'errno'
```

References:

- https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4077
- https://bugs.python.org/issue38254

Comment: Why would `os_error` be a string? Are you doing anything unusual before you hit this stacktrace? I've never seen this, but I have no idea why that super call would be getting a string.

Comment: Appears to be a serialization thing to me. See the update I just posted. It seems that this exception doesn't serialize well.

Comment: Posted the issue on bugs.pythong.org: https://bugs.python.org/issue38229

Comment: Posted the bug report to the wrong place, moved it to aiohttp: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4077

Comment: You can reproduce the issue with `pickle` directly:
`pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError(connection_key, ose)))`

Comment: Also to make your example more representative I suggest using the proper `OSError` initialization, which is e.g. `OSError(1, "Reason string")`, where `1` is the `errno`.

Comment: While debugging this I found something very weird: [ClientConnectorError.__init__](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/38a1ec48ef8fe86bbdbb5fc586f519545220f2d9/aiohttp/client_exceptions.py#L103-L107) receives the `errno` (first arg of the `OSError`) as its own first arg, which gets assigned to `connection_key`! And `os_error` is the reason string, instead of being the `OSError` instance itself.

Comment: This could be due to `ClientConnectorError` being a subclass of `OSError` and some `pickle` quirk (or even bug !?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OSError` has [a custom `__reduce__` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/exceptions.c#L1130); unfortunately, it's not subclass friendly for subclasses that don't match the expected arguments. You can see the intermediate state of the pickling by calling `__reduce__` manually:

```
>>> SubOSError.__reduce__(cce)
(modulename.SubOSError, (1, 'unittest'))
```

The first element of the `tuple` is the callable to call, the second is the `tuple` of arguments to pass. So when it tries to recreate your class, it does:

```
modulename.SubOSError(1, 'unittest')
```

having lost the information about the `OSError` you were originally created with.

If you must accept arguments that don't match what `OSError.__reduce__`/`OSError.__init__` expects, you're going to need to write your own `__reduce__` override to ensure the correct information is pickled. A simple version might be:

```
class SubOSError(OSError):

    def __init__(self, foo, os_error):
        self.foo = foo  # Must preserve information for pickling later
        super().__init__(os_error.errno, os_error.strerror)

    def __reduce__(self):
        # Pickle as type plus tuple of args expected by type
        return type(self), (self.foo, OSError(*self.args))
```

With that design, `SubOSError.__reduce__(cce)` would now return:

```
(modulename.SubOSError, (1, PermissionError(1, 'unittest')))
```

where the second element of the `tuple` is the correct arguments needed to recreate the instance (the change from `OSError` to `PermissionError` is expected; `OSError` actually returns its own subclasses based on the `errno`).

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed and merged to master in `aiohttp` on 25 Sep 2019. I'll update this answer in the future if I note a version that the fix goes into *(feel free to edit this answer in the future to note a version containing this update)*.

Git issue with the fix:

https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4077